# Error openning workbook. Make sure Excel is installed

Tags: excel, uipath

[image][image]I am using IUpath studio and working with excel file.
However, when i try to run, there is an error :
"Error openning workbook. Make sure Excel is installed "

I have excel installed in my PC. I also installed excel in another version. But it still error. Do you have any idea why and what is the solution?

Comment: Did you add excel path to enviroment   variable of windows.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: What's your os? Windows 7 or 10

Comment: I use windows 10

Answer (score 2):

Add Excel path to windows environment and restart your session.

[Add path to windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10)

Comment: I have added excel path to windows environment, but still cant

Comment: What was the error same error or error was changed open a command prompt and type excel and check excel application starts or not?

Comment: i can access excel by typing "excel" in cmd. However, the error still occured. I post the picture.

Comment: Your general problem is linking to excel libraries copy excel dlls beside your .exe file and check again

Comment: which dll? can you specify the name? i found a lot of dll in my folder

Comment: In excel bin folder find them all and copy them

Comment: i attached my excel.exe folder. there is no bin folder.

Comment: Look for dlls besides.exe unfortunately I am in linux right now

Comment: copy the dll from where to where?

Comment: @RaspiSurya copy dlls from excel folder to your debug folder

Comment: I am sorry, but what is debug folder? and what is the location?

Comment: I am sorry, but what is debug folder? and what is the location?

Comment: Maybe iupath has configurations for excel plugins it's better to ask another better question with more in-depth info I am getting confused of your problem

Comment: Debug folder is the folder in which your execution file will be placed Iam not an expert in IUpath find someone expert I hope I could help

Answer (score 0):

I contacted UiPath regarding this issue after trying everything mentioned here as well: https://forum.uipath.com/t/error-opening-workbook-make-sure-excel-is-installed/15009

Their other solution, apart from fixing the registry (which was fine for me), was to perform a full online repair for Office (I was only able to do a quick repair on my laptop) and that fixed this error.